# date value in View is not displayed ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to retrieve data from my sql server. in the table, contained 1 column with date format. 
[image]

I have succeed retrieve the value for the other column it that table. However, the time_stamp column value is missing.

[image]

Is there anyone have this issue before? I dont know why the value for this column is not displayed

here is the detail:
**model**

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> time_stamp { get; set; }
```

**view**

```
           <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.time_stamp)
           </td>
```

**controller**

```
model.feedback = entities.FEEDBACKS.ToList();
```

I think the problem related to the data format, might be in the model or view.
Because the other column is display correctly.

Comment: Check the value of `model.feedback` in your controller. Does each item in the collection contain a value for `time_stamp`?

Comment: Do you have any decorations on the `time_stamp` property ?

Comment: I dont have any decoration for the time_stamp

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. It is because I use the connection created from ADO connection to edmx. And I add the time_stamp manually. So the connection is not updated.

Solution --> rebuild the edmx connection.